# numbers before decimal separator do not align in table column

Tags: tables, fonts, horizontal-alignment, siunitx

I want a table column that is aligned at the decimal separator. For that I use the S column type defined by the siunitx package. However, when I do this, the numbers left of the decimal separator are not aligned at all (nor are the group separators). I am using the MinionPro package and I think the alignment issue is caused by this font. Is there an easy way to solve the alignment problem while keeping the MinionPro font for the (main) text?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: In lieu of an MWE, I have two comments.  (1) Make sure you use the `tabfigures` package which makes use of the fixed-width numerals provided by MinionPro for tables, see the MinionPro documentation.  (2) Use the `group-minimum-digits=4` option of `siunitx` to ensure consistent group of numbers of different lengths.

Comment: With no MWE and that final comment, I think 'too localized'